# What does "A user can unprotect any protected question" mean?

Tags: support, protected-questions

The [Protect Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) help page has the following statements:

> Any question, even a deleted question, can be protected and unprotected, subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - The question must be at least a day old
> - A user can unprotect any protected question

I don't understand the second bullet point. Certainly it doesn't mean "any user can unprotect any protected question" does it? Perhaps it means any user *with the Protect Questions privilege* can unprotect any protected question. I'm kind of guessing here.

It would be helpful if this help page were clarified.

**UPDATE:** [Bug filed and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250041/protect-questions-privilege-page-has-confusing-wording).

Comment: Literal cross-site dupe:  [Meaning of “A user can unprotect any protected question”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244609/175248)

Comment: Thanks for finding this; I had neglected to look on meta.SE. That question has a reasonable answer an explanation, but it doesn't look like the help text has been updated.

Comment: It is kind of a tautology.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It means:

> A user [with this privilege] can unprotect any protected question [even if he wasn't the one that protected it].

This includes even the ones protected by a moderator.

Comment: Great. Now how do we go about getting the text on that page fixed? I'm not sure what the workflow is for this kind of stuff on meta. Should I ask a new question and tag it as a "bug" against the help page, or should I repurpose this one? Or something else?

Comment: @StuartMarks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bug,help-center,privileges

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Posted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250041/protect-questions-privilege-page-has-confusing-wording

Comment: @Braiam, Is there any voting being done? Or can a single 15k user do the unprotecting?

Comment: @Pacerier no, protection isn't by votes. A single user can protect/unprotect any question.

Comment: @Braiam how often do protect/unprotect wars occur?

Comment: @ButtleButkus I imagine they're pretty rare, since few 15k+ users are generally going to have the opinion "No! This question needs *more* answers from anonymous and < 10 rep users!!"

Comment: @ButtleButkus http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=support,stats&title=How+often+protection+wars+occur?

Comment: @Braiam, Link after the question is posted. Not before....